# How to write file to internal storage(/storage/sdcard1)?

Tags: android

My phone(Ienovo A320t) has 3 storage device as below:

System(`/data`), Internal(`/storage/sdcard1`) and External(`/storage/sdcard0`)

I can read or write external storage(`/storage/sdcard0`), my app works very well. But when I try to write something to internal storage(`/storage/sdcard1`), it always fails, no file was created, and also this process did not throw any exception. How can I get a permission to access internal storage(`/storage/sdcard1`)?

Here are some permission I defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_phone_state" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My phone(Ienovo A320t) has 3 storage device as below: System(/data), Internal(/storage/sdcard1) and External(/storage/sdcard0)

In Android SDK terms, `/data` is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), `/storage/sdcard0` is probably [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and `/storage/sdcard1/` is probably [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> How can I get a permission to access internal storage(/storage/sdcard1)?

If my guess is correct, and `/storage/sdcard1` is removable storage, since your device appears to ship with Android 4.4, you do not have access to arbitrary locations on removable storage. You are welcome to use methods like `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the `s` at the end) — if that method returns two or more entries, the second and subsequent ones are directories on removable storage to which you can read and write.

Comment: thanks a lot, and I tried this.getExternalFilesDirs("") in activity, but this method returns only one entry "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files", what's wrong about my code?

Comment: mybe it's my phone's problem, I use another phone, this API works very well.

Comment: @sunjinbo: "but this method returns only one entry "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files"" -- then, from Android's standpoint, apparently you do not have any removable storage, though I would try `null` instead of `""` as the parameter.